# How to increase volume level of sip calls in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

I want to increase volume level of calls in asterisk.I tried with VOLUME function but it doesn't change. I am using asterisk 11.

Answer (score 6):

I had to increase the volume of calls to a call center . According to the documentation of Asterisk 11 must use the VOLUME function; in this way:

```
exten => test,1,NoOp(-- TESTING EXTENSION --)
same => n,Answer()    
same => n,Set(VOLUME(RX,p)=4) ;for 
....   
same => n,hangup()
```

Switches between RX or TX in order to increase reception or transmission.

I do not know exactly what the maximum and minimum value for this function , but 4 worked perfectly in my case.

Adding the argument p also increases the volume of the DTMF tones.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Function_VOLUME

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure the RTP Audio goes through asterisk (rtp media proxy functionality). This can be achieved by the directmedia=no or using different codecs on phones to build a translation path.
Also volume can be changed on most of the endpoint devices as well. It has less impact on network usage and performance. Check soft/hard phone settings.

Answer (score 0):

Volume function work just okay, you can ensure that by record call

Please note, that equipment on either side of call can have auto-level logic which will decrease volume to same value.

Most of softphones have it.

So i can suggest try nice hardphone like cisco 7940 and compare

Comment: I got issue on Iphone only